# In Django, how to find out what URL pattern matched for a request?

Tags: python, django, url, url-pattern

I'm working on an old Django project with a lot of [URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/). Sometimes, it's not clear for me which view was run by the dispatcher. Is there any way to see what URL pattern matched for a particular request in Django?

Comment: You can use `resolve(..)` for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [**`resolve(..)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) for that.

If we define as `urlpatterns`:

```
from django.urls import path
from app.views import some_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('some/<slug:name>', some_view, name='some_view')
]
```

It will return us:

```
>>> resolve('/some/view/')
ResolverMatch(func=app.views.some_view, args=(), kwargs={'name': 'view'}, url_name=some_view, app_names=[], namespaces=[], route=some/<slug:name>/)
```

It thus returns us a [**`ResolverMatch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch). We can query this object like:

```
>>> result = resolve('/some/view/')
>>> result.func
<function some_view at 0x7fc09facf0d0>
>>> result.args
()
>>> result.kwargs
{'name': 'view'}
>>> result.url_name
'some_view'
>>> result.app_names
[]
>>> result.namespaces
[]
>>> result.route
'some/<slug:name>/'
```

Here `func` thus holds a reference to the function that will be triggered, `args` and `kwargs` hold the positional and named parameters in the path respectively, `url_name` the name of the view, etc.

If the path is unclear, you could use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) function instead.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('some/view', some_view_func, name='some_new_view'),
    path('some/<int:pk>', some_view_with_id, name='some_with_id'),
]
```

Without arguments

> Note: This only works for url configurations without arguments.

```
In [1]: reverse('some_new_view')
Out[1]: 'some/view'
```

To match url view names with arguments

```
In [1]: reverse('some_with_id', kwargs={'pk': 1})
Out[1]: 'some/1'
```